# How to prove this determinant is not equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know if this matrix has a name, but I want to prove the determinant is not equal to zero:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1   & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 2^1 & \cdots & n^1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 2^{n-1} & \cdots & n^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}
\neq 0
$$

I know the formula for the determinant is $\sum_P\epsilon_P a_{1,j_1}\cdots a_{n,j_n}$, but I don't see any way to use it or another to prove the above statement.

Background: I want to prove this in order to prove that functions $e^x,e^{2x},..,e^{nx}$ are independent, by using the determinant of the Wronskian and then taking out the $e^x,..,e^{nx}$ from each column, where the above matrix remains. My math skills are not advanced enough to use much more than the Wronskian I am afraid for this task.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the transpose of a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#:~:text=The%20Vandermonde%20determinant%20is%20used,theory%20of%20the%20symmetric%20group.&text=belong%20to%20a%20finite%20field,Reed%E2%80%93Solomon%20error%20correction%20codes.), invertible in your case.

Comment: It is called [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), with variables equal to $1,2,\ldots ,n$.